# Can't figure out why my javascript loop is not working to check presence of object in array

Tags: vue.js

I am working on a liking/unliking button, which works as expected, except that for some reason, it does not seem to be able to check if a user has already liked a post.

Here is my computed value where I attempt to perform the check:

```
isLikedByUser() {
  console.log('this.likes count is: ', this.likes.length)
  console.log('current user.id is: ', this.me.id)
  console.log('these are the likes in the computed value: ', this.likes)
  for(const like of this.likes) {
    if (like.user.id === this.me.id) {
      console.log('true')
      return true
    } else {
      console.log('false')
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

All of the console.log except the final true/false (which always returns false) work.

here is the console output:

```
these are the likes:  (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Post.vue?4c00:79 this.likes count is:  4
Post.vue?4c00:80 current user.id is:  1
Post.vue?4c00:81 these are the likes in the computed value:  (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
Post.vue?4c00:87 false
```

The 2nd element of this array is a "like" with users_id = 1, which should match the current user.id and result in a "true" output, so my thought is that the loop is stopping at the first element, but I am not sure.

Comment: You mentioned array contains property like user_id, and in if statement you are checking user.id. Possibly a mistype?

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo, you should be checking for `like.user_id === this.me.id`.

```js
for(const like of this.likes) {
    if (like.user_id === this.me.id) {
      console.log('true')
      return true
    } else {
      console.log('false')
      return false
    }
  }
```

Also, you can make a less verbose version of the above code by using the `some` function of JavaScript:

```js
if (this.likes.some(e => e.user_id == this.me.id)) {
    console.log(true)
    return true
} else {
    console.log(false)
    return false
}
```

Comment: I figured out the problem. Loop was ending on return, so when the result was false, the for loop would exit before it had checked all of them to find the like that was by the current user.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone coming to this, I figured out the problem. Loop was ending on return, so when the result was false, the for loop would exit before it had checked all of them to find the like that was by the current user. The solution is as follows:

```
isLikedByUser() {
  for(const like of this.likes) {
    if (like.user.id === this.me.id) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false     
}
```